# Objective C how to get a Facebook access token

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm having some trouble pulling a Facebook access token from the web for a Facebook Feed App I'm writing. The problem isn't strictly related to gaining a Facebook token; this just frames the problem. When I go to https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=[APP_ID]&client_secret=[APP_SECRET], I am returned a token on a page that simply says:

```
access_token=464483653570261|cY9NHFBWCDJ9hSQfswWFg0FDZvw
```

How can I parse that from the webpage into my app? I'm relatively new to Objective C (and I've only got a year of basic coding experience), so I tried to use part of a method that I found online to get a JSON feed, combined with a simple parsing method, but it didn't work. The code is as follows:

```
    id getToken = [self objectWithUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/
                           oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&
                           client_id=464483653570261&
                           client_secret=55bb8395ed0293bf37af695f6cdaa1fb"]];
    NSString *fullToken = (NSString *)getToken;
    NSLog(@"fullToken: %@", fullToken);
    NSArray *components = [fullToken componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
    NSString *token = [components objectAtIndex:1];
    NSLog(@"token: %@", token);
```

Both of my NSLogs say that the respective Strings point to (null). I'm not really certain what I'm doing wrong, and I haven't had much luck finding answers on the internet, as I'm not sure what to call what I'm trying to do. I'd appreciate any help, or alternate methods, that you might have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the look of it, the value you're getting isn't JSON, it's just a string.

Try something like this:

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/
                       oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&
                       client_id=464483653570261&
                       client_secret=55bb8395ed0293bf37af695f6cdaa1fb"]];
NSString * fullToken = [NSString stringWithContentsOfUrl: url];
NSLog(@"fullToken: %@", fullToken);
NSArray *components = [fullToken componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
NSString *token = [components objectAtIndex:1];
NSLog(@"token: %@", token);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! However, stringWithContentsOfUrl: has been deprecated in favor of stringWithContentsOfUrl:encoding:error:, and I don't know what to pass to encoding:. How would I find out which encoding the page in question is using?

Comment: Actually, never mind. Deprecated or not, it worked, and that's good enough for now. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Great stuff! I'd try NSUTF8StringEncoding as the encoding, BTW

Comment: Awesome. I've got it in my code, but I'm fighting some other problems now, so I can't test it just yet. Regardless, thanks again!

Comment: I have a question, for example, if I wanto to use search method is it possible to do in this way? Ej: https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/search?q=Ca&type=place&center=20.62494428830279,-87.08271162592534&distance=150&access_token=490474297688828|YMcbSnVGuHsbDX9SCYAK7jbdvbQ

Answer (score 0):

There is a more simple way of getting User's access_token using the ACAccountStore & ACAccountType. Check the Full Code Below:

```
ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
ACAccountType *accountType =  [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];
NSDictionary *FBOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:FACEBOOK_APP_ID, ACFacebookAppIdKey,@[@"email"],ACFacebookPermissionsKey, nil];

[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:FBOptions completion:
 ^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
     if (granted) {

         NSArray *facebookAccounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
         FBAccount = [facebookAccounts firstObject];
         NSLog(@"token :%@",[[FBAccount credential] oauthToken]);

     } else {
         NSLog(@"error getting permission %@",error);
         if([error code]== ACErrorAccountNotFound){
             NSLog(@"Account not found. Please setup your account in settings app"); 
         }
         else {
             NSLog(@"Account access denied");
         }

     }
 }];
```